# Exact location of a tweet

Tags: api, twitter, geolocation, ip-address

I was trying to get the location of a tweet in a app and it occurs if I can obtain the ip of the tweet , I'll be narrow down the location of its origin. So, what I want is there any way to get the ip? Or suggest me a good way to get its best precise location. I've been using python wrapper for twitter, so pls don't say use the user's location or time zone! Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter does not provide IPs for users or tweets. You can check tweet objects to see if the contain a `coordinates`, or `place` parameter. If a tweet does not contain those then the users profile location is the best you can do.

You can see examples of the location values on [tweet objects](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets).

Comment: Nice example but is there any chance of tracing if the geo's disabled?

Comment: User objects contain a boolean `geo_enabled` value.

Comment: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active".   The new URL for this seems to be https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=68008168172683264 ...except I think you have to do more complicated auth stuff nowadays